# Why is PayPal saying Invalid Regular Period even when values are correct?

Tags: paypal, forms, paypal-subscriptions

I am submitting the following form and PayPal always gives an error message that says:

> Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3, and T3 parameters for a subscription.

**Question** : What is wrong with my html form where the A3,P3 and T3 have valid values?

**PayPal Html form for Subscription Payment**

```
   <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="someValidValue">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.xyz/pc.aspx" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="23V125,new,architect" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="A3"  value="200" />
    <input type="hidden" name="T3"  value="M" />
    <input type="hidden" name="P3"  value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name"  value="Gold" />
    <input type="hidden" name="max_text" value="Commit up to 50 loads per month and unlimited viewing/searching" />
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1"> <!-- recurring=yes -->
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1"> <!-- reattempt=yes -->
    <div style="display:inline-block;margin-top:50px;">
        <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to specify `A3`,`T3` and `P3` in lower case. This solved my problem.

Also, always make sure that `a3` does not have a value with more than 2 decimal places; having a value without decimal places for `a3` is fine. So a value of 200 or 200.34 or 200.1 would work, but 200.0000  or 200.345 would not work.

I came across a useful fact regarding this issue on PayPal documentation at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/

> IPN and PDT variable names are case-sensitive. All constant values are lowercase, except those for payment_status, whose constant values have an initial capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the names of the input boxes to lowercase: a3, p3, t3.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" />
```